# Java finding the midpoint between two integers

Tags: java, math, integer-overflow

I'm attempting to find the integer midpoint between two integers. For example mid(2,3) would be 2, not 2.5. I had the below which works fine, but i'd like to work with numbers from MIN_VALUE to MAX_VALUE, and doing so causes overflow so completely incorrect results.

```
public static int mid(int x, int y){
    int midpoint =  (x+y)/2;
    return midpoint;
}
```

I've now got:

```
public static int mid(int x, int y){
    int low = Math.min(x, y);
    int high = Math.max(x, y);
    int midpoint =  (low + high) >>> 1;
    return midpoint;
}
```

This seems to work for values of x and y from 0 up to Integer.MAX_VALUE, however is incorrect if x is a negative number and i'm unsure why that is?

Comment: It also doesn't work if `x + y > MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Do it with `double` and then convert back to int?  Promote the `int`s to `long`s first?

Comment: Can't reproduce wrong behavior on negative integer. The only thing I could verify is that this code is affected by overflow-issues.

Comment: Look up the difference between `>>>` and `>>`. (And use `/ 2`. Don't try to outsmart the compiler, it will bitshift when it's meaningful.)

Comment: @molbdnilo What is wrong with `>>>`?  https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Nothing at all if you're not working with signed integers or not using it for arithmetic. This code is doing both, however.

Answer (score 4):

How about this one?

```
public static int mid(int x, int y) {
   return x/2 + y/2 + (x%2 + y%2)/2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work around with convert to long and back:

```
public static int mid(int x, int y) {
    return (int) (((long)x + y) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Can't `(long) x + y` still overflow an integer?

Comment: If one of the values in an arithmetic operation (+, −, *, /, %) is long, then all values are converted to long type before the arithmetic operation in performed. So `(long)x+y` will return `long`, after that `((long)x+y)/2` will return `long` but still is in `int` range, so the cast to `int` will work

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
public static int mid(int x, int y){
    long difference = (long)y - x;
    long adDiff = difference/2;
    return (long) (x + adDiff);
}
```

You have to cast it to a long so that in the instance where `y-x` is greater then MAX_VALUE you don't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

a >>> operator fills the top bits with zero, unlike >> which extends the sign bit into the top bits.so bitwise operator >> is helpful:

```
public static int mid(int x, int y){
   int midpoint =  (x>>1) + (y>>1);

    if((x&0b1)/0b1==1&&(y&0b1)/0b1==1){
        midpoint++;
    }

    return midpoint;
}
```

for example:
1111 1110(decimal -2) + 0000 0001(decimal 1) = 1111 1111(decimal -1)

1111 1111(decimal -1)>>1 = 1111 1111(decimal -1)

while

1111 1111(decimal -1)>>>1 = 0111 1111(decimal 127)

(java type 'Integer' is 4 bytes,here just to illustrate )

I think this may be useful to understand the result;

Comment: Ok I now see the difference in these operators, but even with >> there seems to be overflow. The mid of Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE should be Integer.MAX_VALUE however is -1, and for mid(MIN_VALUE,MIN_VALUE) is showing 0.

Comment: you can try 'int midpoint =  (x>>1) + (y>>1);',of course,Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE is Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1

Comment: I hava edited the answer.'(x&0b1)/0b1' is to get the last bit code